# Show javascript code ONLY if the visitor is from Specific Country?

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to make an ad on my website which would only show for Visitors from Russia, but don't want other countries for it to see?
what would be the easiest way to create something like this?

Comment: Prompt user with a question that only people living in Russia would know the answer to. If they get it wrong, don't show the ad. simple

Answer (score 0):

Get [MaxMinds GeoLite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) GeoIP databases. From there on, you can compare your visitors IP up against that database.